# SpawnSync doesn't work when using electron-builder

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder, spawn

I am writing an react-electron application and I noticed that when I used electron-builder to build it the binary was stuck when calling "spawn".

With "yarn start" the application can be executed without problems. Only with electron-builder it gets stuck.

Can you help ?

Thanks,

**Update**

It seems that the C++ binary included as part of the program can't be executed within electron. If I give the hardcoded full path to the binary it works but if I give the path from **__dirname** I get an error

```
const GetLocalPath = () => {
  const path = __dirname + "/../cpp_program/"

  return {
    helloWorld: path+ "helloWorld",
    helloWorldRepeat: path+ "helloWorldRepeat"
  }
}

export function helloWorld(){
  // let dir = "/Users/Rick/projects/lala/github/tutorial/electron-tutorial-app/cpp_program";
  let comm = GetLocalPath().helloWorld;
```

**The error message**

```
internal/child_process.js:403 Uncaught (in promise) Error: spawn ENOTDIR
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:562)
    at helloWorldRepeat (/Users/ricky/proje…ar/build/Lib.js:113)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ricky/proje…sar/build/Lib.js:49)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/ricky/proje…asar/build/Lib.js:9
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/ricky/proje…asar/build/Lib.js:5)
    at Object.handleInitialize (/Users/ricky/proje…sar/build/Lib.js:35)
    at TestStateMachine.transition (/Users/ricky/proje…tStateMachine.js:56)
```

This is pretty odd because it works just fine with "yarn start", which is "tsc && electron"

package.json is shown below

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && electron ."
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.myapp",
    "productName": "MyApp",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "public/**/*",
      "src/images/**/*"
    ]
  },
```

**Update ver 2**

Per Alexander's suggestion I have included

```
"asar": false
```

inside package.json

When I excute it I get a different error

```
Uncaught Error: spawn /Users/Rick/projects/lala/github/tutorial/electron-tutorial-app/dist/mac/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/app/build/../cpp_program/helloWorldRepeat ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80)
errnoException  @   internal/errors.js:510
ChildProcess._handle.onexit @   internal/child_process.js:269
onErrorNT   @   internal/child_process.js:465
processTicksAndRejections   @   internal/process/task_queues.js:80
```

Now the error is that there is no "helloWorldRepeat" file inside /Users/Rick/projects/lala/github/tutorial/electron-tutorial-app/dist/mac/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/app/build/../cpp_program/.

The binary is in fact located at

/Users/Rick/projects/lala/github/tutorial/electron-tutorial-app/build/../cpp_program/helloWorldRepeat

Do I have to manually create this folder and paste the binary files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Electron Builder compiles your application and packs all resources into one large archive file (think of it as a ZIP file) which can be read just fine because Electron brings support for this format known as "ASAR".

When running the built program, the code will be read from the archive. This means that `__dirname` will point to a directory inside the archive. The operating system, however, cannot read from the archive. Since you did not actually include the piece of code calling `child_process.spawn ()`, I can only speculate on why you get `ENOTDIR`, which hints that a given path is not a directory when it was expected to be one, but I assume this is because you point to a path inside the ASAR file.

When relying on external binaries, it is a good idea to keep them outside the ASAR archive and programmatically find the path to them (which is quite complex) or by preventing Electron Builder from compiling your app into an ASAR file. However, you would also have to ask Electron Builder to include the executable in the built version of your app. This can be done by modifying your `package.json`:

```json
{
    ...
    "build": {
        "appId": "com.example.myapp",
        "productName": "MyApp",
        "files": [
            "build/**/*",
            "public/**/*",
            "src/images/**/*"
        ],
        "extraResources": [
            "cpp_program/*"
        ]
        "asar": false
    },
}
```

(Replace `"cpp_program/*"` by whatever path pattern matches your desired directory, possibly even replacing `/*` with `/**/*` if there are subdirectories.)

This way, the directory `cpp_program` will be copied to your app's resources directory upon build. This path, according to [Electron Builder's documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extraresources), is `Contents/Resources/` on MacOS. Thus, you will have to modify your path (`__dirname + "../"` will not work because it will point to `Contents/Resources/app`, but `__dirname + "../../"` should; if not, experimenting will lead to the correct path)*. Remember to run Electron Builder every time your C++ executable changes, as the files in the `.app` folder are not linked to their counterparts outside the built app.

---

<sup>*</sup> You can switch between development paths (`__dirname + "../"`) and production paths (`__dirname + "../../"` or whatever) by checking if `__dirname.includes (".app/")`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and now I have "ENOENT" error because the binary files don't exist in this directory. Does this mean that I have to many move the binary files to the location ? Let me update my post.

Comment: @takanoha Please see the updated answer. You'll have to include the binary file's directory as well.

Comment: I see. Yes it does work but the binary files aren't bundled as part of the application. With " npx electron-builder --mac --x64 --dir" I can see the app is built here "dist/mac/MyApp.app" which would dynamically call helloWorldRepeat inside cpp_program. Is there any way to bundle all this inside MyApp.app ?

Comment: That's what the new line in the `"include": []` part of the Electron Builder configuration should do. `.app`s are just directories, you should be able to enter it in Finder and check whether it actually gets copied to the `dist/mac/MyApp.app/Content/Resources/app` folder (not a Mac user though, so can't help you with that).

Comment: Alex, I am still puzzled. Could you please update package.json with "include" keyword so that the binaries will be copied over to inside MyApp.app/ ?

Comment: Ah sorry, I actually meant `"files": []`. My bad. The line `"cpp_program/**/*"` should actually include your binaries. Are they copied or still missing?

Comment: They aren't copied over. MyApp.app does read binaries inside cpp_program/* but not inside MyApp.app :(

Comment: Are they not copied over or is your app unable to read them (two different things)? Also, you can try if `"cpp_program/*"` instead of `"cpp_program/**/*"` helps. Please confirm whether the files are (really) missing in the `MyApp.app/Content/Resources/app` folder.

Comment: The files are still missing iinside MyApp.app/Content/Resources/app/

Comment: Sorry for all the inconveniences. The updated answer should now be correct and lead to the desired results. Btw, `"cpp_program/*"` will only work if the directory is in the same folder as `package.json`.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex ! Your answer works !!!! I noticed when __dirname is used we will need to append "/" so (__dirname + "/../") is the right one. : )