# Electron with python won't run when packaged

Tags: javascript, python, flask, electron, spawn

I am packaging an Electron desktop app that runs a Flask server locally. Whenever I try to run the standalone app that is created from the project I get the error below. When I run the project using npm run I don't get this error and the backend works perfectly. This error is extremely recent and python with the backend has worked perfectly up until this point. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: spawn python3.11 ENOENT
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

JS code

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const expressProcess = spawn('python3.11', [path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'test.py')]);

  expressProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`Flask Output: ${data}`);
  });

  expressProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`Flask Error: ${data}`);
  });

  app.dock && app.dock.setIcon(path.join(__dirname, 'images', 'Logo.png'));

  createWindow();
});
```

Comment: Try using the absolute path to `python3.11`, perhaps the spawned process doesn't inherit environment variables, like PATH.

Comment: I guess that the app is packaged as an ASAR file? If so, try setting `"asar": false` in your build config (if you're using Electron Builder, not sure about Forge), as said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67559497/6786876